# Finding basis of the null space of eigenvector equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKvhc.png)

I'm trying to do part (ii) which asks for the basis for the null spaces of the eigenvector equation with the two respective eigenvalues.

What's the easiest way of doing so? I tried to find matrix C manually by letting matrix C be its each individual component (using algebra) and exploiting the fact that the matrix C is symmetric and the two given results for the multiplication of matrix C, but can't seem to progress much.

Edit:
Now that I've figured out how to find the basis of the nullspace of the eigenspace corresponding to alpha, how do I find the basis of the nullspace of the eigenspace corresponding to beta? I understand that the basis is one-dimensional.

Comment: Hint: the two vectors in the image (whose multiplication with $C$ is shown) are eigenvectors of $C$

Comment: does that mean that the basis would be expressed in terms of alpha too

Comment: $v$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\alpha$ iff $Cv = \alpha v$, or rather, $(C-\alpha I)v = 0$. Thus, $v$ is an eigenvector associated to $\alpha$ iff $v \in N(C-\alpha I)$. You've been given two vectors, both of which are eigenvectors corresponding to $\alpha$, and they are clearly linearly independent, so since you know that $N(C-\alpha I)$ is 2-dimensional, these vectors must form a basis for $N(C - \alpha I)$.

Comment: Do you know that the eigenspaces of a real symmetric matrix are orthogonal?